# meteor: send email | AuthError: Invalid login - 535-5.7.8

Tags: email, meteor

I've installed the email package and tried to sent a test mail, but it presents me with the following error: **AuthError: Invalid login - 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted**

I'm sure the credentials are correct and the code is the same as: https://github.com/ideaq/meteor-email

/server/init.js

```
process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://USERNAME%40gmail.com:PASSWORD@smtp.gmail.com:465/";
console.log(process.env.MAIL_URL);

Email.send({
    from: "from@gmail.com",
    to: "my-email@gmail.com",
    subject: "Meteor Can Send Emails via Gmail",
    text: "test"
});
```

also tried:

```
// configure email later for validation and sending messages
smtp = {
    username: 'myusername@gmail.com',
    password: 'my-pw',
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465
};

process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.username) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.password) + '@' + encodeURIComponent(smtp.server) + ':' + smtp.port;
```

I can't seem to find any other information around this problem or how to followup on it. Who can give me a clue?

Comment: Could you try using the username without "@gmail.com" at the end?

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thx for the suggestions guys! I fixed it by actually turning ON 2-step verification, generate an app password and use THAT as login. Strange solution, but it worked!

Answer (score 4):

1. Solution:  It's the gmail security for less secure apps. Also a quick solution will be to turn off the access [Allow less secure apps](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)
2. Solution: Best way will be to work with 2-Step verification [2-Step Verification](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/180744)

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using OAuth2 and you're facing the issue above, configuring my transporter as shown below resolved the error for me.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 465,
  secure: true,
  auth: {
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
    clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    refreshToken: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_REFRESH_TOKEN
  }
});
```

If you're not sure how to generate the id, secret and token, follow the steps here https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/nodemailer-service-in-node-js-using-smtp-and-xoauth2-7c638a39a37e

Answer (score 0):

Try port 25.
smtp = {
    username: 'myusername@gmail.com',
    password: 'my-pw',
    server:   'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:25
};

Comment: Then I get a Error: connect ETIMEDOUT (seems like a typo, but its copy pasted from terminal)

Comment: did you try adding this inside `server/main.js` as `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;`