# Meteor email with Gsuite, unknown protocol Error

Tags: email, ssl, meteor, gmail

I'm trying to send verification emails to newly signed up users using our Gsuite account, within a Meteor app.

The MAIL_URL is `smtps://me%40myDomain.com:myPassword@smtp.gmail.com:587/`

And this is the error that shows up in my console:

`Error: 140736457798592:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:`

This is sent from my app which uses SSL, and I believe it is set up properly (i.e. certificate is valid and verified by the browser).

Comment: Try port 465. It appears that Meteor confugures `simplesmtp` to use a secure connection only on port 465.

Comment: That is correct, the reason I tried port 587 is because I got an `invalid login` error with 465. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392273/meteor-send-email-autherror-invalid-login-535-5-7-8) fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

I would just add that for anyone who has been following [this article on MeteorChef](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-the-email-package), if you're working in your dev environment without an ssl certificate, you'll need to adjust your `MAIL_URL` to use `smtp` not `smtps`